# TypeError: cannot convert to an int; scalar object is not a number

Tags: python

I am getting an error: TypeError: cannot convert to an int; scalar object is not a number. Could you please help me with the code.

```
def visualize_categories(df,catName,chart_type='histogram',ylimit=[None,None]):
    """
    This functions helps to quickly visualize categorical variables. 
    This functions calls other functions generate_boxplot and generate_histogram
    df: pandas.Dataframe
    catName: str, variable name, it must be present in df
    chart_type: {histogram,boxplot}, choose which type of chart to plot
    ylim: tuple, list. Valid if chart_type is histogram
    """
    print (catName)
    cats = sorted(pd.unique(df[catName]))
    if chart_type == 'boxplot': #generate boxplot
        generate_boxplot(df,catName,ylimit)
    elif chart_type == 'histogram': # generate histogram
        generate_histogram(df,catName)
    else:
        pass

def generate_histogram(df,catName):
    """
    generate histogram of tip percentage by variable "catName" with ylim set to ylimit
    df: pandas.Dataframe
    catName: str
    ylimit: tuple, list
    """
    cats = sorted(pd.unique(df[catName]))
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(cats)))
    hx = np.array(map(lambda x:round(x,1),np.histogram(df.Tip_percentage,bins=20)[1]))
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (15,4))
    for i,cat in enumerate(cats):
        vals = df[df[catName] == cat].Tip_percentage
        h = np.histogram(vals,bins=hx)
        w = 0.9*(hx[1]-hx[0])/float(len(cats))
        plt.bar(hx[:-1]+w*i,h[0],color=colors[i],width=w)
    plt.legend(cats)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.title('Distribution of Tip by '+catName)
    plt.xlabel('Tip (%)')
```

Comment: Can you edit to add some small sample data frame that reproduces the error?

Comment: If you have an error, then you should have a traceback. Please include it in your question.

Comment: TypeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-dd9c73973c97> in <module>()
<ipython-input-88-28800085ee76> in generate_histogram(df, catName)
    118     for i,cat in enumerate(cats):
    119         vals = df[df[catName] == cat].Tip_percentage
--> 120         h = np.histogram(vals,bins=hx)
    121         w = 0.9*(hx[1]-hx[0])/float(len(cats))
    122         plt.bar(hx[:-1]+w*i,h[0],color=colors[i],width=w)

/Users/kv/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in histogram(a, bins, range, normed, weights, density)